# re.split() on a complex string

Tags: python-2.7

I have a string that can vary depending on the input and I need to split them by ':'. For example I may have '`001`:`xxxxx`:banana[1:3]'Number of occurrence of `0, x and 1` may vary. It may or may not have all three. but would have the combination of them.

I have a re.split regular expression that splits individual values but I am messing up with ` and : with in the required strings.

regular expression I have:

`` r'(<.+>[\d+:\d+])|([[^:]+:\d+(:\d+)?])|(`\d+`)' ``

This gives me a list `['001', ':xxxxx:banana', '[1:3]']` What I would like is to have just the values. `[001, xxxxx`, 'banana[1:3]']

Comment: Regex is notoriously bad at anything that has to take the state of matched brackets or quotes into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

suppose a = a  ='001 : xxxxx :banana[1:3]' and the format for the string always string the same though the number of 1s, 0s and x change.

```
a.split(':', 2)
```

output

```
['001', ' xxxxx', 'banana[1:3]']
```

Comment: Please note there is no space '001:xxxxx:banana[1:3]' That was auto generated when I used code tag around them

Comment: @user1958532 Okay I will modify the answer, but the format of the string you mentioned will be the same always I suppose, right?

Comment: they may or may not have all the variations. but would have the combinations. like `'00':banana[1:3]` or `'xxx':banana[1:3]` or all three